# Hibernate JPA, deleting and adding in the same transaction

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

It's been a while since I've used Hibernate, and just now working with it again. I'm using Hibernate JPA.

### Edited Question

How can I delete and add an object in the same transaction? I have a request mapped in the controller to a service layer that reaches to the dao layer. I would like to delete an object, make a copy of that object, and re-add the object, but I think the persistence context is getting flushed, so I can complete the delete, but then I get an detached entity exception when trying to re-add the object at the controller layer. This is probably a newbie mistake...help?!

- User <- **retain**

  - association <- **remove**
  - association <- **remove**
  - association <- **remove**
  - ...
  - association <- **remove**

### Original Question

I'm trying to create a function that will remove all records that have a foreign key with MainRecord. Currently, all tables that have foreign keys with MainRecord are set to cascade on delete, so if I remove MainRecord, it will automatically delete everything.

The state I want is to remove all records, except for the main record, so that it's like the MainRecord just got inserted into the system, and any associations made with it will be saved after this. There's A LOT of tables that use MainRecord though, and I don't want to write a custom query to remove the record from each of those tables, so I was thinking of deleting the MainRecord, creating a copy, and re-adding it to the database.

Though I feel like there should be a way to do this without deleting the MainRecord.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Hope all-delete-orphan will do the job! try exploring it

Comment: I have no idea why you would want to do this, but the error message with detached blabla can be avoidet by resetting the id to `null`.

Comment: I want to complete the delete so I can have the cascade delete effect for all associated records, to avoid manually deleting every reference. the design is such that the parent record (a user) is referenced in many other tables, but a process occurs that requires the user to be 'reset', so all the tables that get created need to be removed, but the user needs to be retained. I may be able to use some combination of the all-delete-orphan function on a particular table though, but I think it would result in a lot of unused records.

Comment: Then why do you need to re-add stuff, if you are just going to blank the whole thing?

Comment: I need to readd the user, but not the child records that get generated.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe I'm approaching this wrong...maybe if I have the client handle the delete, then add, it will work...

Comment: +1 to everyone who commented. Thanks for commenting everyone. It helped me sort through my thoughts and figure out a solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might have been partly how I was delivering the object to the back end; it might have been that the connection was flushing before I completed both transactions; I'm still not sure I understand that exact cause, but I figured out a way to get it working the way I need it to.

I ended up relying on the client to make a call for delete, then make a call for add after the call for delete finished, and this works. I doubt it's ideal...so I'm still open to alternative solutions, but it works...